# HTML Front End Security

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Today I found a security hole in my web application (Pardon me if this is mentioned else where because I couldn't able to find it on SO). Consider this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            intv = setTimeout(function(){test()} , 10000);
            function test(){
                val = document.getElementById('tt').value;
                alert(val);
                intv = setTimeout(function(){test()} , 10000);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input type="hidden" value="10" id="tt">
    </body>
</html>
```

**The Problem:**

This code will alert value of an Input Field with 10 seconds of interval. After first alert I change the input field value in Browser by viewing its source code. And it alerts the value which I added later on, which is not good for me.

**Real Life Scenario:**

I have a virtual classroom where student and teacher both attend a class session. I send the the ajax request after every 5 seconds to update the duration of class at backend and I add `+5` in duration field in db, and later on student has to pay us according to the duration they spent in a class. I am afraid if any smart guy just edit the source code in browser and instead of sending request after 5 seconds he changed to it 1 hour (for sake of argument) to cheat my logic. How to prevent any kind of illegal activity on client side?

Comment: Why don't you use the server's clock? Record the server time when the session starts and again when it finishes then use the values to calculate the lesson length.

Comment: This issue is just not related to this scenario. The question is how to avoid such kind of incident where user is changing the value which they should not be able to change it. Although your suggestion is good.

Comment: There is no way. At that point you are in the clients domain and they have the power to do whatever they want.

Comment: It's very much related to your problem.  It is not related to the way you've chosen to implement it.  Javascript is not a great technology for your requirement.  Ash is giving you better advice.  Listen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do to prevent users from changing JavaScript values.

Instead you should validate input on the server.

In this case, as suggested in the comments, you should log the start and end time using the servers time.

Comment: ok i got it. Apart from the scenario i mentioned. What if i have to kick a user out after one hour. Obviously those calculations are done on the client side.

Comment: Just refuse to send them any more data (is it a video feed? Cut it off!)

Comment: Store that the user has been removed and check this in requests for data. If they have been removed - ignore their request for data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply detect every request they make (if it's a virtual classroom there is something going on right?) and on the server-side save when they accessed it to somewhere (database). Have a table of start and end of a session.